# On Linux there is a 3GB/1GB kernel option. How do I do this in Windows 7 32-bit?

Tags: windows, memory, virtual-memory

I have 4GB RAM installed. PAE is off. How do I tell the Windows 7 32-bit kernel to allocate 3GB virtual paging area to **user mode** and only 1GB to **kernel space**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start a command prompt with Administrative privileges (write `cmd` in the Start search and right-click cmd.exe and select Run as Administrator). Write the command `bcdedit /set IncreaseUserVA 3072` This increases the user address space to 3GB and shrinks the kernel address space to 1GB.

Do take care: If you have a badly coded driver this change can cause it to crash.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, you can add the [/3GB flag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff556232%28VS.85%29.aspx) to your boot.ini file to turn on OS level support.  However, this will only allow applications that also have the appropriate flag (IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE) turned on in their process header (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg487508.aspx) for more details).

Comment: This won't work on Windows Vista and higher. They don't have boot.ini. But that link does explain how it works on Windows Vista so thanks.